# Explanation for a linear algebra problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

From Axler's linear algebra chapter 3 question 21.

> > Prove that any linear map from $\operatorname{Mat}(n,1,\Bbb F)$ to $\operatorname{Mat}(m,1,\Bbb F)$ is given by a matrix multiplication. In other words, if $T$ is the linear map, $B\in \operatorname{Mat}(n,1,\Bbb F)$, then $TB=AB$ for some $m\times n$ matrix $A$

I don't quite understand the point of this question. As if we have any linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces, say $T\in L(V,W)$, then we can always find bases for $V$ and $W$, then there is a linear map between $L(V,W)$ and $\operatorname{Mat}(m,n,\Bbb F)$. This is in fact how matrices are introduced in the book, as a way to represent linear map. So I thought the statement would be trivial. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think, but not sure, the point is to show that it is literally an equality in this case. The image of $B$ under $T$ is actually equal to  $AB$.

Comment: @quid Oh is it that generally for vector space, writing $\vec w= T \vec v$ in the matrix form, we are actually transforming the equation into $M(w)=M(T)M(v)$. But in this case, we have $M(B)=B$, so transforming a column matrix is simply multiplying it by some matrix.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the point, that is when you take the 'canonical' basis for the space then $M(B) = B$.

Comment: @quid Ah, I get it now. Thanks for the reply :)